# Trigger to add opportunity and Account name to "Items to Approve" "Description"

Tags: approval-process

We have a custom object (sales_credit__c) that is related to opportunities, and can be submitted for approval.  As documented, the fields that can be included in the "Items to Approve" list is very limited.  Because of this, we would like to write a trigger that adds the related opportunity and account names to the "Items to Approve" "Description" (this will give users a better idea of what they are approving).

[image: Items To Approve]

I have tried several different objects/fields that seem to be related to approvals, but so far not luck.  Any advise/suggestion would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your Approval Process Page Layout.

This is done clicking edit button at the top of the Approval process you want customize.

If the field you want to add does not exist in the object, perhaps you should consider to add a formula field to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks @ransommule for your quick response, this is very helpful if approving individual items, but not is trying to approve multiple items (Unless I am missing something).  My ultimate goal is to be able to display the name of related objects under the items to approve list.